Accuracy extremely low when using different dataset with tensroflow recommenders
I have followed the tutorial on the TensorFlow Recommenders website and when trying to adapt it to my dataset, the accuracy suddenly becomes extremely low.. like 0.27 for their dataset and 0.0027 for mine.
I have managed at some point to adapt it correctly and have a similar accuracy on my dataset but somehow I ruined the code and now I can't make it back up.
This is the code that adapts the dataset:
movies_metadata = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/movies_metadata.csv')
    ratings=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/ratings.csv')
    ratings = ratings[['userId', 'movieId','timestamp']].rename(columns={'movieId': 'movie_id',     'userId': 'user_id'})
    movies_metadata = movies_metadata[['id', 'title']].rename(columns={'id': 'movie_id', 'title': 'movie_title'})
    ratings['movie_id'] = ratings['movie_id'].astype(str)
    movies_metadata['movie_id'] = movies_metadata['movie_id'].astype(str)
    combined_dataset = pd.merge(ratings, movies_metadata, on='movie_id', how='inner')
    combined_dataset= combined_dataset.sample(100_000,random_state=1)
    combined_dataset_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({
    'user_id': combined_dataset['user_id'].astype(str).values,
    'movie_title': combined_dataset['movie_title'].astype(str).values,
    'timestamp': combined_dataset['timestamp'].values
    })

    movies = combined_dataset_tf.map(lambda x: x["movie_title"])

    unique_user_ids = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(combined_dataset_tf.batch(1_000).map(
    lambda x: x["user_id"]))))
    unique_movie_titles = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(movies.batch(1_000).map(
    lambda x: x))))

Next, this is the adapted movie model:
from typing import Dict, Text
    class MovieModel(tf.keras.Model):
  
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    max_tokens = 10_000

    self.title_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
          vocabulary=unique_movie_titles,mask_token=None),
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_movie_titles) + 1, 32)
    ])

    self.title_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=max_tokens)

    self.title_text_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      self.title_vectorizer,
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_tokens, 32, mask_zero=True),
      tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    ])

    self.title_vectorizer.adapt(movies)

    def call(self, inputs):
    print(inputs.dtype)
    return tf.concat([
        self.title_embedding(inputs),
        self.title_text_embedding(inputs),
    ], axis=1)


And this is the movie model:
class MovielensModel(tfrs.models.Model):

    def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    super().__init__()
    self.query_model = QueryModel(layer_sizes)
    self.candidate_model = CandidateModel(layer_sizes)
    self.task = tfrs.tasks.Retrieval(
        metrics=tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
            candidates=movies.batch(128).map(self.candidate_model),
        ),
    )

    def compute_loss(self, features, training=False):
    # We only pass the user id and timestamp features into the query model. This
    # is to ensure that the training inputs would have the same keys as the
    # query inputs. Otherwise the discrepancy in input structure would cause an
    # error when loading the query model after saving it.
    query_embeddings = self.query_model({
        "user_id": features["user_id"],
        "timestamp": features["timestamp"],
    })
       movie_embeddings = self.candidate_model(features["movie_title"])

       return self.task(
        query_embeddings, movie_embeddings)

In the picture, it is attached the picture with the results on the validation, showing the low accuracy. Thank you for the responses, please!!

Hi@Denisa Birisan, you've put a lot of effort into adapting the TensorFlow Recommenders tutorial to your dataset, but you're running into issues with model performance.Ensure that your data preprocessing is consistent with the tutorial’s dataset.For example:
The tutorial might use specific preprocessed formats or types that are different from your data. Make sure your user_id and movie_title are consistently processed and mapped.

The embedding dimensions (e.g., 32) you use may not be optimal for your dataset. Experiment with different dimensions to see if they impact performance.
Your MovieModel class seems to have both a StringLookup and TextVectorization layer. Verify that these layers are used correctly:
StringLookup is used to convert strings into integer indices for embeddings.
TextVectorization is for processing raw text data into token sequences, which might not be necessary if you use StringLookup.
